# "Year format requires to enter 4 digits" .subscript in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an upcoming project.

I have a validation program to write, beginner's level.

I've written the code most part, but in case the user inputs the year in 2 digit form I need to convert it into 4-digit form.

Then I need to declare a new variable and extract using '.subscript' the 4-digits from the National Identification Number which is a 13 digit number.

I've written most of the code so far ( I won't post it all of it here), but the code won't execute when it reaches yearString = yearString.substring(2,4).

```
function cnpVal() {
var cnpString = document.getElementById('lblcnp').value;  //13 digit number
var dayString = document.getElementById('txtday').value;
var monthString = document.getElementById('txtmonth').value;
var yearString = document.getElementById('txtyear').value;  //2 or 4 digit number

arrayCnp = cnpString.split('');


if (yearString.length != 4) {
    alert("Year format requires you to enter 4 digits");
    return false;
    }
    else {
        yearString = yearString.substring(2,4);
    }
```

Basically I need the yearString variable declared and working for a 4 digit year, i.e. 1987.

Obviously it won't work as 1987 = ["1", "9", "8", "7"] is a 4 string array, but I don't have a string at index 4.

I hope I've made myself understood and sorry for the ignorance. I stand to be corrected.

Greets.

Comment: *but the code won't execute when it reaches yearString = yearString.substring(2,4)* - What error does it show in console?

Comment: No error in the console. It just returns "return false' and exits.

Answer (score 0):

`yearString = yearString.substring(2,4);` will extract the last 2 digits from `yearString`. `String.prototype.substring` accepts a start index as the first argument and an optional end index which is not included in the extraction, so `yearString.substring(2,4)` will take the character at index 2 and 3, and does not include the character at index 4.

Documentation for `substring` is available [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

You could also try `String.prototype.substr(start, length)` which takes the start index of the sub string you need as the first argument and how many characters you want to extract as the second argument.

Documentation for `substr` is available [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)